# Listview with html enabled android

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have some html entries in my database & i want to render them as HTML rather than normal text

below is my java code of that activity
i am retrieving data from firebase 
the content in my database look like this

```
&lt;a href=&#039;google.com&#039; target=&#039;_Blank&#039;&gt; Click Here &lt;/a&gt;
```

and i want it to convert & display as normal html

> `find code here https://pastebin.com/raw/9KdiEEx4`

Edit:

i want this

```
&lt;a href=&#039;google.com&#039; target=&#039;_Blank&#039;&gt; Click Here &lt;/a&gt;
```

to become this

```
<a href='google.com' target='_Blank'> Click Here </a>
```

& get displayed as normal html

my java code is above 
please help me

Comment: Rather than posting a link to your paste, you should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also let us know anything else that you've already tried, issues you encountered, and anything else you can think of that would help to illustrate your problem.  The more information you can provide, the better we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Can you give as a concrete example on what have you in your database and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: my content in database look like this 

[code]
text for activities here&lt;a href=&#039;https://google.com&#039; target=&#039;_Blank&#039;&gt; Click Here to View&lt;/a&gt;
[/code]


i cant use single or double quote so i am encoding everything 
& i want anchor tag to work in my app 
so i want to render it as normal html

Answer (score 2):

For android version < Nougat :

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

For android version >=  Nougat:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

Comment: i dont have any text view 
& all of my html entities are converted into code like &gt; and &lt;